# How can I make my Raspberry Pi act as a hotspot and broadcast two different signals?

Tags: wifi

I have a Raspberry Pi B4 and I need to make it broadcast more than one Wi-Fi signal.

I have Wlan0 which is the original wifi of the device,
I also have a USB Wi-Fi adapter that appears as Wlan1.

How can I make my Raspberry Pi act as a hotspot and broadcast two different signals?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [As Access Point (WiFi Repeater): How to set up multiple WiFi/SSID](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/108894/as-access-point-wifi-repeater-how-to-set-up-multiple-wifi-ssid)